# How to ensure the two schematic diagrams are equivalent?

Tags: simulation, schematics

I've tried copying the schematic diagram of a typical circuit from the datasheet, but I'd like to ensure the correctness of each connection. Is there a way to somehow match one schematic diagram against another?

If simulation is the only thing closest to such a test, which simulation is most useful?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that simulation would help?

Comment: You can't simulate a PDF file, so you'll have to copy and check the schematic by hand anyways. I find that as you follow the instructions to select component values you end up understanding the schematic to the point where it's harder to make errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "canonical" form of a schematic diagram is a netlist. However, in order to compare two netlists, you need to make sure that the component names and the node names of the two schematics are identical, which may require setting up a mapping of some sort between the two. Then, you go through the netlist node by node, and make sure each node connects to the same pins of the same components.

I don't know of any existing tool that does this, but it would be fairly easy to set up in any scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.).

Comment: IC design tools can compare two net lists, but you would need to carefully enter the reference schematic. Not suggesting that this is viable, but the software exists.

Comment: Mathematicians dubbed this [Graph Isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism).

Answer (score 10):

Yes. You print out the two schematics and then check each component and connection manually. As you have checked each one highlight it with a yellow marker. When you get all done the whole schematic should be all yellow.

Along the way keep a pink highlighter handy. Whenever you find a mistake or mismatch use that color to highlight and this will be your reference for all the mistakes when it comes time to update the schematic.